# Ajax в yii

Tags: php, yii

В общем такой вопрос: как из экшена контроллера передать назад модель? Если отправлять назад из контроллера в нужную вьюху текст, то все гуд:

```
     `public function actionUpdate($id)
            {   
                        $auction_id = $_GET['auction_id'];
`                      `$model=$this->loadModel($id);       
                        $text = 'some text';    
                        echo $text; 
            }`
А если таким же образом отправлять модель, то yii будет ругаться на то, что он ожидает строку, а не объект.
Как быть?
```

UPD: Во вьюхе используется AjaxLink такого вида: `CHtml::ajaxLink(
         CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png'),
             CController::createUrl('additional/update/id/'.$value['id']),
             array(
                 'type' => 'POST',// method
                 'success' => "function( data )
        {
          //  popup_show('popup_apps'),
            alert(data)
        }",
                 'data'=>array('id'=>$value['id']),// DATA
                 'cache'=>'false',
                 'update' => '#mposter',// что обновить :)
             )).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильно я понял что версия YII у вас 1?

не совсем понял куда назад надо вернуть модель и зачем?

где будет ругаться YII?

ну и где ругатся будет YII?

action

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id)
//еще код

//передаем модель во вьюхе
$this->renderPartial('файл вьюхи', array('model'=>$model))

}
```

код вьюхи

```
//получаем атрибут модели
echo $model->id;
```

кстати если нада просто отправить сериализационную модель обратно, то можно обходиться без вьюх

к примеру

action

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id)
//еще код

echo json_encode($model);

}
```

уважаемый вы по моему что то вообще путаете и не разбираетесь что такое вьюха и что такое контроллер!!!

1.контроллер обрабатывает запросы на сервер - те же Ajax не исключения. ИМЕННО ТУТ И НИГДЕ БОЛЕЕ МЫ И РАБОТАЕМ С ДАННЫМИ ПРИШЕДШИМИ ИЗ ВНЕ - ПРОЩЕ ГОВОРЯ ПРИСЛАНЫЕ ЮЗЕРОМ (НУ И НЕ ТОЛЬКО).

2.В контроллере при необходимости создается модель, Вообще чтоб уже совсем на пальцах контроллер готовит данные для представления (с использованием модели или нет -пофигу!!!!!). А вот уже контроллер вызывает вьюху (ФАЙЛ ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЯ) и передает туда необходимые данные и все. В ИДЕАЛЕ во вьехе только HTML теги и и подключение зависимых css и js если нада. ВО вьюхе минимум ЛОГИКИ.

если прочитали это то попробуйте переформулировать вопрос а то у вас неизвестно откуда и кудато обратно должна во вьюху вернутся модель

так а нафига вам в ответ на ajax запрос отсылать целую модель ?? отправьте необходимые данные из модели либо xml форматом либо Json форматом и все. НА клиенте (в браузере) с помощью js разбирите ответ и делайте что вам нада. Вы не 'сможите' отправить полноценную модель из PHP в область видимости JS со всеми методами - да и не к чему ето.

ДА и кстати не путайте: ' и вот эту модель я отправляю обратно во вьюху через echo json_encode($model);' - ЭТО НЕ ОТПРАВКА МОДЕЛИ ВО ВЬЮХУ - это отдача ответа сервером КЛИЕНТУ  (БРАУЗЕРУ, ПРОГРАММЕ И ПРОЧЕЙ ХРЕНИ)!!!!!!!!! а в своем ответе я вам привел пример отдачи модели во вьюху - смотрите еще раз).

Если вы не умеете работать на клиенте (в браузере) на JS с телом ответа на посланный Ajax Запрос - то тут уже вам ни контроллеры не вьюхи нафиг не нужны - они кончились скрипт отработал и отдал контент по вашему запросу  - их тут нету!!!!  Вам тогда нада читать как парсить на JS XML и JSON форматы.. и YII  тут вообще не причем

Comment: Все правильно. Версия 1. Во вьюхе есть ajaxlink, который передает нужный id в actionUpdate, в котором должен произойти происходит поски по первичному ключу в модели и полученные данные отдаются назад во вьюху.

Comment: echo json_encode($model);
Это то что нужно, но как во вьюхе прочитать эту модель? решения типа data['title'], или data->title или data.title не работают. Как Работать с тем, что получает назад ajax в виде json данных?

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю разницу между вьюхой и контроллером. Во вьюху должна отдаваться модель по ajax запросу (на лету) исходя из id, которые уходят в контроллер методом .post в самом ajax запросе. Вся логика примерно такая: я получаю во вьюхе нужный id, отправляю его через ajaxlink методом POST в нужный екшн нужного контроллера, где по этому id происходит выборка из базы в виде модели ($model=$this->loadModel($id);), и вот эту модель я отправляю обратно во вьюху через  echo json_encode($model);
Вопрос в следующем: как во вьюхе на лету прочитать из этой модели нужные данные?

Comment: так а нафига вам в ответ на ajax запрос отсылать целую модель ?? отправьте необходимые данные из модели либо xml форматом либо Json форматом и все. НА клиенте (в браузере) с помощью js разбирите ответ и делайте что вам нада. Вы не 'сможите' отправить полноценную модель из PHP в область видимости JS со всеми методами - да и не к чему ето

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Разобрался. Сделал как вы и посоветовали (Отправил нужные данные json-ом и на клиенте распарсил).